# statistical test to see which type is the most frequent in each group

Tags: r, statistical-significance, spss, multiple-comparisons, frequency

I have four groups of speakers, and I have the count of verbs, adjectives, nouns, and adverbs per each individual in each group.
I would like to see which of these grammatical type is the most frequent in each speaker group. what is the suitable statistical test to compare this data?
Here is the example head of my data, in each group i have 15 individuals.

```
        Nouns   Verbs   Adjectives  Adverbs
Group1  2       6       0           10
Group1  4       2       0           6
Group1  2       0       0           13
Group1  3       0       1           16
Group1  3       0       0           6
Group2  4       3       0           15
Group2  3       3       0           11
Group2  0       0       0           8
Group2  2       1       0           5
Group3  4       1       0           10
Group3  4       1       0           3
Group4  2       2       0           5
Group4  3       1       0           27
Group5  5       2       0           11
Group5  4       5       0           15
Group5  4       0       0           12
```

Comment: Looks like you have 5 groups.

Comment: You have 5 repeats in group 1.  Does that mean that it represents a sample of 5 of the 15 individuals in group 1?

Comment: @MichaelChernick for the sake of example, i only provided sample data and couldn't include the 15 individuals in each group, of course.